Is it possible to create broken symlink (reparse point) from PowerShell?
Is it possible to create a broken symbolic link (meaning destination does not exist when link is created) using PowerShell on Windows 11 and on NTFS filesystem?
And if so will it mimic UNIX behavior so that when destination later gets created the link will become valid?
I tried New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink ... without and with -Force and that scriptlet won't allow me to create link to non-existent destination with error: New-Item : Cannot find path '<path>' because it does not exist.
I know it is possible to create valid link and then remove its destination which renders the link dangling, but I am asking specifically about creating broken link from scratch.
